# Magento2 custom theme with another custom theme as parent, overriding problems

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-theme, theme-overriding

In this project we had one frontend custom theme working, to do some customizations. That is working fine. Let's call that **Theme1/custom** (with **Magento/blank** as parent)

Now we have created a new frontend custom theme, let's call it **Theme2/custom**, whose parent is **Theme1/custom**

Both themes are working, but we are experiencing some issues when trying to override some layouts & templates

Let's say we have one customized template in `app/design/frontend/Theme1/custom/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` & now we need to override that same file in the new custom theme, so we have placed our changes in `app/design/frontend/Theme2/custom/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

I am starting to think this approach is not valid when dealing with custom themes extending custom themes... Because project still loads the **Theme1/custom** one

Cache & static content are fresh, and permissions are ok

Any ideas?

**update**

This issue appears to affect only Magento_Catalog module... which makes that totally weird...

Comment: That method is valid, I have been working on a site that has an identical fallback. Magento Blank > Theme 1 > Theme 2 and it works fine

Comment: Mmm... Maybe we have missed some file in theme configuration then, but it's strange, as some overrides are working fine

Comment: can you paste composer.json of your Theme 2 please? or tell me if you have there any reference to Theme1?

Comment: Nope there is no reference to any of the custom themes in composer.json, all the theme code is inside app/design/frontend

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/230807/3566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird problems usually have weird solutions

All was working fine, but some catalog categories in project had checked attribute "Use parent category settings", and that parent category had forced the original **Theme1/custom**

Comment: That sounds like a potential bug, surely that should only apply to settings and not themes. Unless you set the theme against that category via a setting?

Comment: I suppose someone made that configuration change in root category, when original theme was designed. I mean, that was a human action

Answer (score 0):

Please check your parent tag `<parent>Magento/blank</parent>`

In theme.xml file (path Vendor/theme/theme.xml)

And run all commands.

**And double check your theme names**

In your example path they started from Capital letters

Comment: But the parent of Theme2 should be Theme1/custom, if that's what you mean

Comment: http://joxi.ru/4Ak7R3YIyykpJA
Should start from small letter

Comment: This should work. Look for typo

Comment: Typo in examples were just after changing real names for the ones posted, they are fine in filesystem... this is tricky :S

Comment: Maybe you can share your file structure and content of main theme files
There is mine:
http://joxi.ru/MAjya0wu44keb2

Comment: No problem with file structure... I have updated the post, this affects only Magento_Catalog module... other module overrides are working fine

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/230807/3566